# Not working in putting the text in the middle of the box in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I want to put text in the middle of the box in CSS3, but it's not working for some reasons.

Here's my code snippet (with code from Angularjs):

```
    <div class="a" ng-repeat="i in l | filter:query">
            <a class="b" href="{{i.a}}">{{i.b}} {{i.c}}</a>
    </div>
```

And here's my css:

```
.b {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin: 8px;
height: 20px;
width: 100px;
}
```

And even if I add `vertical-align: middle;` to the above CSS, it doesn't put the text in the middle of the box... why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `css` `table-cell`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/31/

```
.b {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.a {
    display: table;
    height: 200px;
    border: black thin solid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. With a little trial and errors, I found that `float: left;` caused the issue here - without it, your code is working well. However, I want to put those boxes horizontally, since the actual number of boxes is not one - it's automatically created in the `ng-repeat` process from Angular.js. So is it feasible to use `float: left;` and still put the text in the middle, too? Or any alternatives to put those boxes horizontally (without using `float: left;`)?

Comment: OK, adding `.a { display: inline-block; }` and now everything is working well. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

vertical-align requires a lot of things to work right...

easiest method , and what I do, is just use line-height

so do

```
.b { 
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

adjust number of pixels accordingly, but that will center the text vertically for you

Answer (score 0):

`float` kills `display` and so `vertical-align` if avalaibe.

inline-blocks element can be vertical-align aside text, other inline-boxes or on the line-height.

In your case , line-height alone will give height of parent (if unprecised) and set the link on it, right in the middle :), no need to give an inline-block display to `<a>` unless you need it to size it for instance (or whatever else style that needs layout) .

If `.a` has an height, give it an equal line-height. 
Line-height works fine as long as you have one line of text.

if you want to use inline-block, and set middle alignement from itself it won'nt work, you need at least 2 elements as another inline-boxe, so it can center from something ... an extra box or pseudo-element might help.

```
.a {height:300px;}
.a:before {
content:'';
height:100%;
}
.a:before, .a a {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Else, `vertical-align` works on content of `<td>` or element wich receive a `display:table-cell;`. `.a` could then receive a `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align` and eventually an `height`. Usually it needs a parent as `display:table` to work fine.

```
.a {
display:table-cell;
height:200px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I have no special links on tutorial for vertical-align , on W3C it is confusing somehow since both vertical-align for inline-box and cell content are dispatched in different documents.